# GitHub for Desktop won't let me add a pull request to a repo stored on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have my repositories on my USB stick. And on GitHub. When I started the Program the first time, it scanned all my disks. It found one on my USB stick which is also on GitHub. But it didn't find the other two also on the Stick, and ALSO on GitHub. It just added one as a local repo, and I added the other one too. So I had one repo showing as a book icon under the heading "GitHub" (and a forked one) and two with a PC icon under the heading "Other".

So I headed over to the repo settings and set the remote path to my GitHub URL. Then, the repo was listed under the heading GitHum, but a right click still won't give me the option to "View on GitHub", nor have I the ability to create a pull request for that specific project.

How can I tell GitHub for Desktop, to enable these features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

I solved this problem by (as stated in the question) changing the .git URLs to the GitHub URLs (the ones in the web browser). Then I restarted GitHub for desktop. This has solved this weird glitch.

## TL;DR

Just remove the `.git` from the end of your repo-URL in GH Desktop.